# I have valid F-1 visa. Do I need another transit visa for a US connecting flight from a 3rd country?

Tags: visas, usa, customs-and-immigration, transit

I have an F-1 visa in the US and I was planning on flying home after exams, but before going back home I want to spend some time in Canada where I have a valid ten-year multiple-entry visa. The cheapest flight available requires me to fly back into the US for a connecting flight. My status is still valid. Do I need to get a new transit/visitor's visa (in addition to my F-1 visa) in this situation, even if I am just passing through the airport for a few hours? Thanks for your attention!

Comment: As long as you are entitled to F-1 status, you can use that status to enter the US for transit.  If your program of study has ended, however, you are not entitled to F-1 status.  So the answer depends on whether you are going to return and continue your studies in the US.

Comment: thanks @phoog - I am literally just transiting through an American airport and I will come back to the US for my second semester in two weeks. I was told before that a transit visa is unnecessary as long as my F-1 is still valid and I'm still in school. Is that a valid reason for entry?

Comment: Who told you that, and why don't you trust them?

Answer (score 2):

If you're allowed to enter for visit or residency, you can also enter for transit. A visitor or residency visa is thus superior to a transit visa.

This goes for all countries in the world.